# Why does Travertine have vis own pronouns in On the Steel Breeze?

Tags: alastair-reynolds, poseidons-children

In Alastair Reynolds' *On the Steel Breeze*, the physicist Travertine has vis own set of personal pronouns, something like

> *ve* (nominative)
>     *ver* (accusative)
>     *vis* (genitive)
>     *verself* (reflexive)

Why?

I thought of the character as male, but maybe I missed something.

Comment: I read a lot of Greg Egan myself, so when I first encountered Tavertine in 'On a Steel Breeze' I assumed he was an artificial intelligence... I'm less than a quarter of a way through it myself so I don't know if he is or isn't an AI yet - although it seems the society in this universe is against it - so perhaps he/she's just gender neutral. The future is so progressive, haha. I actually came here to see if he is in fact an AI, because other than the pronouns they don't really allude to him being one.

Comment: I'm pretty sure ve's not an AI.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Alastair Reynolds was asked about these pronouns in his blog comments (many people have simply assumed it was a typo or a mistake in the printing process). He replied in [another comment](http://www.alastairreynolds.com/novel-delivered/#comment-3037):

> They’re not errors – those are gender-neutral pronouns for the character Travertine.

This means the pronouns are a deliberate attempt not to imply a male or female gender for the character. Gender-neutral pronouns aren’t in particularly common use, but they do exist, and this is just one such example.

There’s a good explanation of gender-neutral pronouns, and a list of others that you might encounter, [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gender-specific_and_gender-neutral_pronouns). Of this particular pronoun, *Ve*, it says this:

> Proposed by New Zealand writer Keri Hulme some time in the 1980s. Also used by writer Greg Egan for non-gendered artificial intelligences and “asex” humans.

Note that the Wikipedia entry also has a list of the different forms of the pronoun, which seems to line up with the list in your question.